# Why isn't the theme changing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, jsx

Description:

I've implemented a theme switching button in my React application to toggle between light and dark themes. However, I'm encountering an issue where clicking the button doesn't result in the theme changing as expected.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my application:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import RecruitmentList from './components/RecruitmentList';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };

  return (
    <div className={`App ${darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode'}`}>
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="mode-switcher" onClick={toggleDarkMode}>
          <div className={`toggle ${darkMode ? 'toggle-dark' : 'toggle-light'}`} />
        </div>
        <RecruitmentList />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.mode-switcher {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.toggle-light {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.toggle-dark {
  background-color: #333;
}

.toggle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.toggle-light::after {
  left: 4px;
}

.toggle-dark::after {
  left: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Despite clicking the "Toggle Theme" button, the theme remains unchanged. I've checked the event handling and state updating logic, but I can't seem to identify the issue.

Could someone please help me understand why the theme isn't changing when the button is clicked? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7rRy.png)
[dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GmSy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems just fine.
But how about you try this?

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
}

.mode-switcher {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.light-mode .App-header {
  background-color: #fff; /* Light mode background color */
  color: #000; /* Light mode text color */
}

.dark-mode .App-header {
  background-color: #282c34; /* Dark mode background color */
  color: white; /* Dark mode text color */
}
```

And if this doesn't work, you could close your React app and then restarts it. But be sure to check if there are errors on your console first.

Comment: I just wanted to drop you a quick note to say a huge thank you for helping me out with my code. Seriously, I was totally stuck, and your input made all the difference!

It's awesome to have someone like you who's not only skilled but also super cool about lending a hand. Thanks to your tweaks and tips, my code is now up and running smoothly. Couldn't have done it without you!

I owe you one big time. Let's grab a coffee (or your beverage of choice) sometime soon as a token of my appreciation. Looking forward to it!

Answer (score 0):

It had multiple issues.

1. You didn't add the classes for dark-mode and light-mode
2. You header was taking the entire height
3. You need to add some content or full height to you `.App` class

I have corrected the CSS. Replace your CSS with below code -

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100vh;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.mode-switcher {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.toggle-light {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.toggle-dark {
  background-color: #333;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: #333;
}

.light-mode {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.toggle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.toggle-light::after {
  left: 4px;
}

.toggle-dark::after {
  left: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

This toggle seems to be working fine with above changes.

Comment: I just wanted to drop you a quick note to say a huge thank you for helping me out with my code. Seriously, I was totally stuck, and your input made all the difference!

It's awesome to have someone like you who's not only skilled but also super cool about lending a hand. Thanks to your tweaks and tips, my code is now up and running smoothly. Couldn't have done it without you!

I owe you one big time. Let's grab a coffee (or your beverage of choice) sometime soon as a token of my appreciation. Looking forward to it!